# which tag should I Select in CSS and which css rules should i imply so the items will appear in columns (mega menu)

Tags: html, css

```
    <ul class="categories">

            <li><a href="#" >All categories</a>

                <ul class="sub-menu"></br>
                <li><a href="#">item </a></li>
                <li><a href="#">item</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">item</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">item</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">item</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">item</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">item</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">item </a></li>
                <li><a href="#">item</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">item</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">item</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">item</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">item</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">item</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">item </a></li>
                <li><a href="#">item</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">item</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">item</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">item</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">item</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">item</a></li>


                </ul>

            </li>       
    </ul>


CSS:

  .sub-menu {
display: none;

}

.categories li:hover .sub-menu {
    display:block;
}
```

I'm trying here to make a mega menu.
in this case which tag should I Select in CSS and which CSS rules should I imply so the items will appear in columns (mega menu).

thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`columns`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/columns)

```css
.sub-menu {
    -webkit-column-count: 3; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    -moz-column-count: 3; /* Firefox */
    column-count: 3; /* Edge, IE10+ */
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 5px 0;   
}

.sub-menu li  {
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
}

.sub-menu li:first-child {
  margin-top: 0;
}
```

```html
<ul class="categories">
    <li><a href="#" >All categories</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li><a href="#">item </a></li>
            <li><a href="#">item</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">item</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">item</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">item</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">item</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">item</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">item </a></li>
            <li><a href="#">item</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">item</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">item</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">item</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">item</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">item</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">item </a></li>
            <li><a href="#">item</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">item</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">item</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">item</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">item</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">item</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>       
</ul>
```

Fiddle with `display: block` on `hover` **[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/b8bvmgk1/2/)**